# Getting MW3 Double XP without Mtn Dew or any prestige tokens

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Today (November 13th, 2011), while playing MW3 on Xbox I noticed I was getting Double XP for most of the day. I know that you can enable it a few different ways, but I didn't do anything special this weekend. This was player XP, so like kill confirmed was giving me 100 score for each tag.

While playing, my accounts tag (not sure if thats the right name, but where the emblem, title, and more show up) had a red/orange 'XP' icon in the top right.

I didn't do anything that I can think of to enable this. And I haven't done anything special in the game (and I didn't pay for Elite). I was a beta tester for Elite though.

I couldn't find anything online stating it was a double XP weekend either.

My question is - how are other ways to get Double XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signing up for CoD Elite (even the free version) grants you 2 hours worth of double XP, but they were having issues with Elite, so not everyone got it right when they signed up.  The website is still down, but you can check their Twitter feed, where they're telling multiple people that they should be getting their double XP boost soon:

https://twitter.com/#!/CallOfDutyElite

Chances are you signed up for the Elite website at some point, and that's where your 2 hours came from.  Incidentally, when you view your playercard in the barracks, you'll not only see the gold XP icon in the upper right, but towards the bottom there's a timer that shows how much Double XP time you have remaining.

Comment: I checked my playercard, and then in the barracks, yes, it was a 2 hour double XP (which surprisingly I've only used up 30 min of but feels like 3 hours), and im 99% from Elite.

Comment: It only counts time you spent in-game, so you could play for a couple of hours and only use up 30-40 minutes of it due to downtime between rounds, trying to find a lobby, host migrations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Mountain Dew promotion, there are two ways to get double xp:

When you prestige, you get a prestige token which you can spend on a variety of different items, including 2 hours of double xp.

Xbox Live has double xp weekends on a semi-regular basis, the weekend stated above being one of them.  Generally, these weekends coincide with the release of a new map pack or game.

Comment: A few weekends ago was double XP on Black Ops and MW2, but I didn't see anything for MW3, and playing on a friends xbox was not giving his player double XP.